# DecimalFormat and rounding for fixed point numbers

Tags: java, precision, floating-accuracy, decimalformat

While working with [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), I was puzzled by its behavior when rounding numbers with fixed-point patterns. To make things more specific:

```
double n = 2082809.080589735D;

// Output the exact value of n
System.out.println("value:       " + new BigDecimal(n).toPlainString());

System.out.println("double:      " + n);

DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00000000");

System.out.println("format:      " + format.format(n));
System.out.println("format (BD): " + format.format(new BigDecimal(n)));
```

The output of this snippet is:

```
value:       2082809.080589734949171543121337890625
double:      2082809.080589735
format:      2082809.08058974
format (BD): 2082809.08058973
```

From the first output line we notice that the actual value is *below* the half-way point between `2082809.08058973` and `2082809.08058974` (`...49...`). Despite this, `DecimalFormat` rounds the value upwards when provided with a `double` argument.

Other values are rounded downwards:

```
value:       261285.2738465850125066936016082763671875
double:      261285.273846585
format:      261285.27384658
format (BD): 261285.27384659
```

This does not happen in all cases:

```
value:       0.080589734949171543121337890625
double:      0.08058973494917154
format:      0.08058973
format (BD): 0.08058973

value:       0.2738465850125066936016082763671875
double:      0.2738465850125067
format:      0.27384659
format (BD): 0.27384659
```

It seems to me that the formatted string for a `double` is rounded using [half-even rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) based on an imprecise decimal value produced with something along the lines of `Double.toString()`, rather than the actual mathematical value represented by the `double` in question. When the formatted precision is very close to (or more than) the precision provided by the `double` type, things start becoming somewhat random.

In all the cases presented above, formatting the corresponding `BigDecimal` seems to perform the rounding as expected.

I was unable to find any specification describing the proper behavior of `DecimalFormat` in this case.

- Is this behavior documented somewhere?
- From a correctness point of view, wouldn't rounding the actual mathematical value be preferable?

  I understand that people writing `1.0...35` would (naively?) expect it to be rounded to `1.0...4`, but `1.0...35` may not even be representable in any primitive data type available in Java...

**EDIT:**

I have submitted a report to Oracle - hopefully they will be able to either fix or clarify this issue.

Comment: @RickRegan: it does not appear to have made it through to the public bug database just yet. I will update my question as soon as it does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was apparently a [known issue](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7131459) that has been [fixed in Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html#A999387).

`DecimalFormat` in Java 8 is supposed to always perform the rounding correctly, regardless of the format chosen by the developer. Naturally, this results in slightly incompatible behavior when compared to Java 7 - whether this is important or not would depend on the specifics of each application.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html), java uses IEEE 754 - 1985, while you (from the comments asumed IEEE754 - 2008)

> The floating-point types are float and double, which are conceptually
>   associated with the single-precision 32-bit and double-precision
>   64-bit format IEEE 754 values and operations as specified in IEEE
>   Standard for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic, ANSI/IEEE Standard
>   754-1985 (IEEE, New York).

Use `setRoundingMode()` of `DecimalFormat` to specify the rounding behavior.

> Is this behavior documented somewhere?

See javadoc of [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) and the detailed in [RoundingMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html)
And in [IEEE 754 - 1985](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) and in JLS (first statemen in this answer)

Default, as documented is the Half even rounding mode.
HALF_EVEN

```
public static final RoundingMode HALF_EVEN
```

> Rounding mode to round towards the "nearest neighbor" unless both
>   neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even
>   neighbor. Behaves as for RoundingMode.HALF_UP if the digit to the left
>   of the discarded fraction is odd; behaves as for
>   RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN if it's even. Note that this is the rounding
>   mode that statistically minimizes cumulative error when applied
>   repeatedly over a sequence of calculations. It is sometimes known as
>   "Banker's rounding," and is chiefly used in the USA. This rounding
>   mode is analogous to the rounding policy used for float and double
>   arithmetic in Java.

Comment: I am reasonably familiar with the specifics of IEEE-754. The double value has the value reported via `BigDecimal` - it's `Double.toString()` and friends that *interpret* things by rounding to the decimal with the least digits that allows distinguishing a `double` from the next and previous `double` values...

Comment: And what is your open question? The javadoc tells the rounding mode.

Comment: The `half-even` mode is used for tie-breaking in rounding operations. The way I see it there is no tie here, so I would expect numbers to be rounded to the nearest decimal...

Comment: tie braking? I dont know that term. The spec of HALV Even Rouning dont use that term.

Comment: A rounding *tie* is when the mathematical value falls *exactly* half-way between two potential rounding results. The breaking mode is how the tie is resolved by selecting one of the two. For half-even rounding ties are resolved by selecting the option with an even last digit - IEEE-754 uses the term `tie-to-even` IIRC...

Comment: It still seems for me that it is not true when you say "The double values has the value reported via BigDecimal)".  This may be the cause of the confusion. Dont use BigDecimal to output the value of the double. Use the double

Comment: As far as I can tell from my IEEE-754-2008 copy, it always refers to rounding the infinitely precise result, not some intermediate value. On the other hand, I found a couple of references mentioning that older versions of the standard did not require correct rounding on base conversions...

Comment: have you checked the  IEEE-754-1985 ?

Comment: I checked with IEEE-754-1985. It requires correct rounding up to and including 17 significant digits for a `double`...

Comment: Then you should find a way to output that 17 significant digits whitout using BigDecimal. It seems that your are exactly at the limit, try with fewer fractions digits after the comma. I expect that it then behaves as you expect.

Comment: I already have my own formatter that does this correctly. I was just surprised by the behavior of `DecimalFormat`...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this could be due to double rounding.

The output marked "double" looks like it's correctly rounded to 16 digits. The output marked "format" looks like it's rounded from the 16 digit value (rounded half to even).

(I'd need to see more examples to verify this.)